# How to define a type extension for T[] in F#?

Tags: c#, arrays, f#, extension-methods

In C#, I can define an extension method for a generic array of type T like this:

```
public static T GetOrDefault<T>(this T[] arr, int n)
{
    if (arr.Length > n)
    {
        return arr[n];
    }

    return default(T);
}
```

but for the life of me I can't figure out how to do the same in F#! I tried `type 'a array with`, `type array<'a> with` and `type 'a[] with` and the compiler wasn't happy with any of them.

Can anyone tell me what's the right to do this in F#?

Sure, I can do this by overshadowing the Array module and add a function for that easily enough, but I really want to know how to do it as an extension method!

Comment: what does "for the life of me" means :) ?

Comment: Extending `System.Array` was my first thought, but a type parameter and cast would be needed unless you're okay with `obj`.

Comment: @Chuck Norris - means 'I can't ... even after I tried very hard'

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You have to write the array type using 'backtick marks'  - like this:

```ml
type 'a ``[]`` with
  member x.GetOrDefault(n) = 
    if x.Length > n then x.[n]
    else Unchecked.defaultof<'a>

let arr = [|1; 2; 3|]
arr.GetOrDefault(1) //2
arr.GetOrDefault(4) //0
```

**Edit**: The syntax ``` type ``[]``<'a> with ... ``` seems to be allowed as well. In the F# source (prim-types-prelude.fs) you can find the following definition:

```ml
type ``[]``<'T> = (# "!0[]" #)
```

Comment: @Daniel: Experimenting. I tried to find anything in the spec/docs but no success.

Answer (score 11):

Good question. I can't figure out how to extend `'T[]` but you can take advantage of the fact that arrays implement `IList<_>` to do:

```ml
type System.Collections.Generic.IList<'T> with
  member x.GetOrDefault(n) = 
    if x.Count > n then x.[n]
    else Unchecked.defaultof<'T>

let arr = [|1; 2; 3|]
arr.GetOrDefault(1) //2
arr.GetOrDefault(4) //0
```

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no legal syntax in F# to add an extension member to array types, so this is probably the best alternative (offhand I can't think of any drawbacks, other than the fact that this method also appears on any other IList types).

Comment: @Daniel - holy crap, you're right! 'T [] does implement IList<'T>! I had no idea! not sure if that makes sense to me though, an array takes a continuous block of memory, right? so the add operations will surely have to re-allocate for the whole new array every time, which seems to me as something you should discourage and encourage the use of List<T> (which has an internal buffer it manages) instead.

Comment: `IList<_>`'s mutating members, `Add`/`Remove`, etc, throw `NotSupportedException`. Try: `([|1|] :> System.Collections.Generic.IList<_>).Add(2)`

Comment: @kvb - my memory is a sieve for stuff like this :)