# How to extend 'T?

Tags: generics, f#

I'm trying to write an extension for `'T`, basically the following in C#:

```
public static T With<T>(this T obj, Action<T> action)
{
    action(obj);
    return obj;
}
```

I tried to translate it to F#:

```
[<Extension>]
type Ext =
    [<Extension>]
    static member With<'T>(obj: 'T, action: Action<'T>): 'T =
        action.Invoke(obj);
        obj;
```

and

```
module Extensions =
    type 'T with
        member this.With(action: Action<'T>): 'T = Ext.With(this, action);
```

But this yields the error "Unexpected keyword 'with' in type name." in the last snippet.

A search returned this, but it obviously works only for array types: [How to define a type extension for T[] in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836167/how-to-define-a-type-extension-for-t-in-f)

How can I extend the generic type `'T`, or is there any workaround?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that you can accomplish this as follows:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type Ext =
    [<Extension>]
    static member With(obj, act) =
        act(obj)
        obj

// example of usage
"a".With(fun s -> printfn "%s" s).With(fun s-> printfn "%s" (s + "2"))
```

You don't really need the explicit types (generic or otherwise) at all. F# will infer the necessary types based on the body of the method.

Of course, you could accomplish this in a more F#-esque way without using extensions at all:

```
let withval = 
    fun act value ->
       act(value)
       value

// example of usage
"a"
   |> withval (fun s -> printfn "%s" s)
   |> withval (fun s-> printfn "%s" (s + "2"))
```

Comment: @ScottNimrod Good point, but if I used `with'` there, I'd have to use it everywhere. Not worth the trouble in my opinion.