# How to define an extention method for a non-generic array?

Tags: arrays, f#, extension-methods

I cannot figure out what is the correct syntax to define an extension method on a non-generic array. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11836167/how-to-define-a-type-extension-for-t-in-f) deals with generic arrays, but trying a similar construct for a byte array doesn't work.

I have tried a lot of options:

```
type Byte ``[]`` with 
type byte ``[]`` with
type Byte array with
type byte array with
type array<Byte> with
type array<byte> with
type []<Byte> with
type []<byte> with
```

as well as all of these constructs wrapped in double backticks or parenthesis, but nothing works. I downloaded the language specification, but it only has a generic array example.

Comment: Have you tried `byte[]`?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin Yes, with no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is likely a quirk with Optional Type Extensions, which [can get pretty funky when generics are involved](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/type-extensions#generic-limitation-of-intrinsic-and-optional-type-extensions). I'd use an extension method like this instead:

```
open System.Runtime.CompilerServices

[<Extension>]
type ByteArrayExtensions =
    [<Extension>]
    static member inline Sum(xs: byte[]) = Array.sum xs

let f() =
    let xs = [| byte(1); byte(2); byte(3) |]
    xs.Sum()
```